# Tkinter add picture after 5s displayed

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi can you please help me for this probleme (I'm sorry I'm not that good at english)
I want the picture (photo 1) to be added after the tkinter has displayed from tkinter.
I need the the photo 1 to appear after 5 seconds knowing that this is only one module of a "hole code"
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
import instructions_traits

x = float()
x = 0.0
aClique =0
Mafenetre = None
varcc = 0

def add():
    global x
    global Mafenetre
    x+=0.001
    Mafenetre.after(1,add)

def apparaitre(Canevas):
    global photo1
    photo1 = PhotoImage(file="homer simpson.gif")
    item1 = Canevas.create_image(300,200,anchor=NW, image=photo1)
    add()

def Clic(event):
    global aClique
    global x
    global varcc
    global Mafenetre

    if aClique == 0:
     aClique = 1
    print (x)
    if x <=0.350 and x >=0.2:
        varb=0

    if x >=0.351:
        varb=5
    Mafenetre.destroy()
    instructions_traits.play(varcc, varb)

def play(varc):
    # Creation de la fenetre principale (main window)
    global Mafenetre
    global varcc
    varcc = varc
    Mafenetre = Tk()
    Mafenetre.title('jeu')
    Mafenetre.configure(width=1550,height=700)

    # Image de fond
    photo = PhotoImage(file="fond homer.gif")

    # Creation d'un widgetCanvas (zone graphique)
    Largeur = 1550
    Hauteur = 700
    Canevas = Canvas(Mafenetre,width = Largeur, height =Hauteur)
    Canevas.bind('<Button-1>', Clic)
    item = Canevas.create_image(0,0,anchor=NW, image=photo)
    Canevas.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 10, pady = 10)

    """Mafenetre.after(5000,apparaitre(Canevas))"""
    time.sleep( 25 )

    apparaitre(Canevas)

    Mafenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `Mafenetre.after(5000, lambda: apparaitre(Canevas))`

Comment: A side note: variable names in Python are canonically `lowercase_with_underscores` (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).